# How to prove $4\mid n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove that $4\mid n$ ?

We know
$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_3}+\cdots+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}+\frac{x_n}{x_1}=0.$$
and $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ is $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: You can even prove a stronger statement: $$\frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_3}+\cdots+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}+\frac{x_n}{x_1} \equiv n \mod 4.$$

Comment: @TMM Yes, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove using induction that
 $|x_i|=|x_j|\neq0, \ \ \forall  \ i,j\Longrightarrow\frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_3}+\cdots+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}+\frac{x_n}{x_1}\equiv n \pmod 4:$
$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_3}+\cdots+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}+\frac{x_n}{x_1}=\\
\frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_2}{x_3}+\cdots+\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_1}+\left(\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}+\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{x_1} \right)\equiv \\ \equiv n-1 +\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}+\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{x_1} \pmod 4\equiv \\ (\text{cases }x_{n-1}=\pm x_n)\equiv n \pmod 4.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what happens when you change the sign of just one of the $x_i$?

Comment: Just to cash this out, since others have now provided full answers, if you change the sign of one of the $x_i$, you change the sign of two components of the sum leaving the rest unchanged. If these had opposite signs originally, then the sum is unchanged. If they originally had the same sign, the sum changes by $\pm 4$. So you can successively change all the $x_i=-1$ to $x_i=+1$ without changing the value of the sum modulo 4. By the time you have finished, every term is equal to 1, and the sum is equal to n.

Answer (score 2):

All the $x_i/x_j$'s in the sum is 1 or -1. Therefore you need an even number of them to make the sum 0, since every time you have a 1 you must have another -1 to cancel it out and vice versa. Multiplying toghether all the $x_i/x_j$'s, you get 1. So an even number of $x_i/x_j$'s equal -1. Then since there are as many $x_i/x_j$'s equal to 1 as $x_i/x_j$'s equal to -1, $n$ is twice that even number, hence divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i = (-1)^{a_i}$, where $a_i \in \{0, 1\}$. We are given:
$$\sum_{\text{cyclic}} (-1)^{a_i + a_{i+1}} = 0$$
Note that $(-1)^{x} = 1-2x$ for $x \in \{ 0,1\}$. Hence we always have
$$\sum_{\text{cyclic}} (-1)^{a_i + a_{i+1}}  = n - 2 \sum_{\text{cyc}} ((a_i + a_{i+1}) \mod 2)$$
Thus 
$$n = 2 \sum_{\text{cyc}} ((a_i + a_{i+1}) \mod 2)$$
Since $\sum_{\text{cyc}} ((a_i + a_{i+1}) \mod 2) = 2\sum a_i = 0 \mod 2$, we deduce that $n$ is divisible by $4$. We also find that in general, $\sum \frac{x_i}{x_{i+1}} \equiv n \mod 4$.